# Pretty way to send cookie?

Tags: symfony, cookies

```
$cookie = new Cookie('my-cookie','cookie');
$response->headers->setCookie($cookie);
$response->send();
```

This code causes problems in case to use redirect

```
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('my_route');
```

or use SensioFrameworkExtraBundle

```
/**
 * @Template()
 */
public function showAction()
{
     return array('entities' => $entities);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By following the [API doc](http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.html#method_redirect), `$this->redirect` Create a new `RedirectResponse` object so your prepared response with cookie is not used anymore.

You need to create a new `RedirectResponse` object, set the cookie and return it.

You can do something like that.

```
$response = new RedirectResponse();
$cookie = new Cookie('my-cookie','cookie');
$response->headers->setCookie($cookie);
return $response
```

Same thing for `return array([...])` that will create a new `Response` object too.

Comment: Please indicate if my answer help you! ;)